# Polynomial division in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

For which value of $n$ is $x^3-x$ divisible by $2x-1$ modulo $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\,\ \color{#0A0}{2x}\!-\!\color{#C00}1\!:\ 0 \equiv 8(x\!-\!x^3) \equiv 4(\color{#0A0}{2x})\!-\!(\color{#0A0}{2x})^3\!\equiv 4(\color{#C00}1)\!-\!(\color{#C00}1)^3\!\equiv 3,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ 2x\!-\!1\mid 3,\ $ so $\ \ldots$

Note: $\rm\,\ 3(1\!-\!2x)(1\!+\!2x\!+\cdots+(2x)^{n-1})\, =\, 3(1\!-\!(2x)^n)\: \Rightarrow\,\  2x\!-\!1\mid 3\, \ \ (mod\,\ 3(2^n))$

Adding $\rm\ x^3\times prior\ $ to $\rm\ (1\!-\!2x)(1\!+\!2x)x\, =\ x\!-\!4x^3\ $ yields 
$$\rm \begin{eqnarray}(1\!-\!2x)\,(x\!+\!2x^2\!+\!3x^3\!+\!6x^4\!+\!12x^5\!+\cdots+ 3(2^n) x^{n+2}) &\,=\,&\rm x - x^3\! - 3(2^n) x^{n+3}\\ &\equiv&\rm x-x^3\ \ (mod\,\ 3(2^n) )\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 3):

I'll attmpt an answer that does not involve tons of explicit numbers. The first thing to observe is that we are talking about divisibility in a ring with zero divisors if $n$ is composite, which is quite unusual. Therefore we should take care to avoid reasoning only valid in integral domains.

If the leading coefficient of a polynomial is invertible, then we can just do Euclidean division, even in the presence of zero divisors (and even over a non-commutative ring if that were necessary; it suffices to specify on which side one is dividing). So it is clear that the case that $n$ is even will be the troublesome one. Now if $d$ is the greatest odd divisor of $n$ and $n/d=2^k$, then $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z_n\cong\Z_{2^k}\times\Z_d$ by the Chinese remainder theorem, and therefore $\Z_n[x]\cong\Z_{2^k}[x]\times\Z_d[x]$. Saying the image in $\Z_n[x]$ of $P=x^3-x$ is a multiple of the image of $Q=2x-1$ amounts to saying that this holds for the respective images of $P,Q$ both in $\Z_{2^k}[x]$ and in $\Z_d[x]$.

In $\Z_d$ the coefficient $2$ is invertible, so dividing a polynomial in $\Z_d[x]$ by $\bar Q=2x-1=2(x-\frac12)$ gives as remainder the evaluation of that polynomial at $x=\frac12$. For $\bar P=x^3-x$ this evaluation is $\frac18-\frac12=\frac38$, which is nonzero unless $d\mid 3$, in other words we have divisibility here only if $d\in\{1,3\}$.

In $\Z_{2^k}[[x]]$ the geometric series $\frac1{1-2x}=\sum_{i\geq0}2^ix^i$ breaks off for $i\geq k$, and it follows that $2x-1$ is *invertible* in $\Z_{2^k}[x]$. Therefore the image of $P$ in $\Z_{2^k}[x]$ is always, trivially, divisible by the image of $Q$.

Therefore the answer to the question is "for those $n$ whose greatest odd divisor is either $1$ or $3$" (explicitly $n=2^k3^l$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ and $l\in\{0,1\}$).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$x^3-x=(2x-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{3}{8}\right)-\frac{3}{8}=\frac{1}{8}\left[(2x-1)(4x^2+2x-3)-3\right]\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\,\ \color{#0A0}{2x}\!-\!\color{#C00}1\!:\ 0 \equiv 8(x\!-\!x^3) \equiv 4(\color{#0A0}{2x})\!-\!(\color{#0A0}{2x})^3\!\equiv 4(\color{#C00}1)\!-\!(\color{#C00}1)^3\!\equiv 3,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ 2x\!-\!1\mid 3,\ $ so $\ \ldots$

Note: $\rm\,\ 3(1\!-\!2x)(1\!+\!2x\!+\cdots+(2x)^{n-1})\, =\, 3(1\!-\!(2x)^n)\: \Rightarrow\,\  2x\!-\!1\mid 3\, \ \ (mod\,\ 3(2^n))$

Adding $\rm\ x^3\times prior\ $ to $\rm\ (1\!-\!2x)(1\!+\!2x)x\, =\ x\!-\!4x^3\ $ yields 
$$\rm \begin{eqnarray}(1\!-\!2x)\,(x\!+\!2x^2\!+\!3x^3\!+\!6x^4\!+\!12x^5\!+\cdots+ 3(2^n) x^{n+2}) &\,=\,&\rm x - x^3\! - 3(2^n) x^{n+3}\\ &\equiv&\rm x-x^3\ \ (mod\,\ 3(2^n) )\end{eqnarray}$$

---

**Note**: Mathgem's comment is right, so I copied his answer and marked as community wiki. Please un-accept this answer as soon as you see this and accept his.

Comment: This is wrong, e.g. $\rm\ mod\ 6\!:\,\ x^3\!-x \equiv (2x\!-\!1)(3x^3\!+\!2x^2+x)\ \ $

Comment: I think it would be better to preserve your original answer (which may well be helpful to the OP and readers). To do so you could simply preface the answer with a remark like "This answer concerns only the special case where $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field, i.e. the case $n = p$ prime..."

Comment: @MathGems I agree, but not as the accepted answer. Maybe a mod can do something?